# Grep and inserting a string

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a text file with a bunch of file paths such as -

```
web/index.erb

web/contact.erb

...
```

etc. I need to append before the

```
</head>
```

a line of code, to every single file, I'm trying to figure out how to do this without opening each file of course. I've heard sed, but I've never used it before..was hoping there would be a grep command maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xargs can be used to apply sed (or any other command) to each filename or argument in a list. So combining that with Rom1's answer gives:

```
xargs sed -i 's/<\/html>/myline\n<\/html>/g' < fileslist.txt
```

Comment: c'mon, guys, don't you know that there's more to sed than subsitute command? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
while read f ; do
    sed -i '/<\/head>/i*iamthelineofcode*' "$f"
done <iamthefileoffiles.list
```

or

```
sed -i '/<\/head>/i*iamthelineofcode*' $(cat iamthefileoffiles.list)
```